# Internal error occurred while generating SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've created a simple API using the AWS API Gateway user interface (swagger exported below):

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "2017-06-15T21:29:34Z"
  title: "Clone from OTAUpdate"
host: "3ks9wfuui3.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
basePath: "/test"
schemes:
- "https"
paths:
  /users:
    post:
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - in: "body"
        name: "CreateUserRequest"
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/CreateUserRequest"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "200 response"
        400:
          description: "400 response"
        500:
          description: "500 response"
definitions:
  CreateUserRequest:
    type: "object"
    required:
    - "emailAddress"
    - "password"
    properties:
      emailAddress:
        type: "string"
        description: "email address of the user"
      password:
        type: "string"
        description: "password of the user"
    title: "CreateUserRequest"
```

When I stage my API, I can generate *every* SDK except Java. When I try to generate the Java SDK I get an error message:

> Internal error occurred while generating SDK

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After banging my head against this for a while, I managed to isolate the cause of this problem. In my "model" descriptions, including

```
"additionalProperties": false
```

directly caused the issue, whilst removing that line resolved the issue.

After some Googling, it appears this is currently an unresolved bug in the API Gateway service:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=223666

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question. Saved me lots of frustration.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Really disappointing that AWS has not been able it to fix this for 3,5 years.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran in to this error.  In case it helps anyone, it looks like API Gateway doesn't support the "allOf" field.